# Inject DbContext with Autofac

Tags: entity-framework, autofac

I have the following EntityFramework context:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDbContext {
}
```

Where IDbContext is the following:

```
public interface IDbContext {
  DbEntityEntry Entry(Object entity);
  IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors();
  Int32 SaveChanges();
  Task<Int32> SaveChangesAsync();
  Task<Int32> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
  DbSet Set(Type entityType);
  DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
} // IDbContext
```

What is the correct way to configure DbContext injection with Autofac?

With StructureMap I had the following:

```
For<IDbContext>().Use(x => new Context());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many ways, depending on scope you need, conventions etc.

Example:

```
containerBuilder
  .RegisterType<Context>()
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Gorgon: Is there a reason for using AsImplementedInterfaces() instead of specifying the interface, eg., As<IDbContext>? And why not use InstancePerRequest()?Thank You.

Comment: Specifying interface(s) explicitly is fine. It's a matter of taste, conventions, discipline, etc (I prefer automagical stuff with conventions). InstancePerRequest() is fine if you're strictly in a web context, but won't work otherwise. InstancePerLifetimeScope() assumes you're aware of the scope and control it by some means yourself (e.g. create one per thread in a batch job).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your constructor expects to receive a DbContext factory `Func<IDbContext>`
so you'll be able to get new instances of DbContext on each call and dispose them on your own, you should use:

```
builder.RegisterType<Context>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency().ExternallyOwned();
```

You might want to take a look at https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html